# How to display Image on Xaml Xamarin Forms on MVVM

Tags: xaml, xamarin, mvvm, xamarin.forms, prism

I have tried to display and image from Mobile camera using Media Plugin. but It does not display after select the image.  I am using MVVM.
I'd appreciate any help.

```
        private byte[] imgAsBytes;
        private ImageSource imageSource;

        //constructor

        public NoticesAdminViewModel()
         {
            _connection = DependencyService.Get<IConnection>().GetConnection();
            UploadImage = new DelegateCommand(async () => await GetImage());
         }

        public DelegateCommand UploadImage { get; set; }

        public ImageSource DisplayImageSource
        {
            get { return imageSource; }
            set
            {
                imageSource = value;
                SetProperty(ref imageSource, value);
            }
        }

        public async Task GetImage()
         {
            file = await DependencyService.Get<IMediaFile>().GetFile();

           //file is not null
            DisplayImageSource = ImageSource.FromStream(() => file.GetStream());

         }

        //My Xaml

        //Display Image Here
         <Image 
            Aspect="AspectFit"
            HeightRequest="200"
            Source="{Binding DisplayImageSource}"
            WidthRequest="200"/>

         // Button to call image

          <Image Source="camera.png" HorizontalOptions="Center">
             <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding UploadImage}" />
             </Image.GestureRecognizers>
          </Image>
```

Which file returns the MediaFile content successfully, and I can upload the image to server,  but the Xaml to display image is blank.

What have I done wrong?
Thanks

Comment: AFAIK you can't bind the ImageSource to a Command: `Source="{Binding UploadImage}"`

Answer (score 0):

First, your code shows you're binding the image's Source to UploadImage, but you'd want it to be bound to your ImageSource property.

Also, in your GetImage() method, you are copying the file contents to a memory stream, copying that into a byte array, but you never use it. Why?

You then immediately dispose both the file and stream and setup the image source pointing to file.GetStream(), but you've already disposed that file.

Try cutting out all that and just do:

```
public async Task<ImageSource> GetImage()
 {
    file = await DependencyService.Get<IMediaFile>().GetFile();

    ImageSource = ImageSource.FromStream(() => file.GetStream());

    return ImageSource;
 }
```

Comment: Hi Ben, thanks for you response.  I am using the memory stream to upload the image file to remote server and it is working fine.  I tried you answer but no image displayed on screen. Still struggling.

Comment: Are you sure the OnPropertyChanged event is firing. I ask, because I just noticed you are setting the imageSource filed before calling SetProperty. That SetProperty method likely only fires the event if the backing field has changed, but if you set it prior to calling it, it won't be different. You can likely remove imageSource = value;